# Boundedness of a class of everywhere defined operators

Tags: functional-analysis

$\textbf{Question. }$ Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A: X \rightarrow X$ be a linear operator that is defined on the whole of $X$. Let $X^*$ denote the space of linear functionals on $X$ and $B : X^* \rightarrow X^*$ be a linear operator defined on the whole of $X^*$ with $(Bf)(x)=f(Ax)$ for any $x \in X$ and $f \in X^*$. Show that $A, B$ are bounded operators.

The question can be viewed as showing that an everywhere defined, "adjointable" operator $A$ is necessarily bounded.

I know that a simply everywhere defined operator could be unbounded. But I have not found any clue in showing the boundedness with the above additional condition. Perhaps the Uniform Boundedness Principle could be helpful.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this should follow from the closed graph theorem: If $(x_k,Ax_k) \to (x,y)$ then $f(Ax_k) \to f(y)$ and by assumption $f(Ax_k) \to f(Ax)$. Hence $f(Ax)=f(y)$ for each $f \in X^\ast$, so $Ax=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Closed Graph Theorem**: Suppose that $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and $Ax_n \to y$ in $X$. Fix $x^* \in X^*$. Then

$$  \langle Bx^*,x_n \rangle =\langle x^* , Ax_n \rangle \to \langle x^*, y \rangle  $$
but
$$ \langle Bx^*,x_n \rangle \to \langle Bx^*,x \rangle = \langle x^*,Ax \rangle$$
and so
$$\langle x^*,Ax \rangle= \langle x^*, y \rangle. $$
Since $x^*$ was arbitrary, $y=Ax$. This shows that $A$ is bounded.

(I prefer to use the notation $\langle x^*,x \rangle $ instead of $x^*(x)$)